# Is "I wish I had studied English further" correct?

Tags: past-perfect, perfect-constructions

I want to express regret for not having studied more English when I was a kid. Is this sentence correct?

> I wish I had studied English further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from [here](http://www.eslbase.com/grammar/wish):

> We use wish + past perfect to express a regret, or that we want a
>   situation in the past to be different.

Comment: and the adjective further is well applied?

Comment: I see no problem with it; it would mean e.g. that you studied some English when you were a child, but that you regret not having studied it more.

Comment: I can't imagine a native speaker using "further" this way. The most natural phrasing is "studied English more". (There's nothing technically wrong with it though, it just sounds unnatural.)

Comment: Maybe it does sound a bit unnatural, but it's not **way** off. I mean, these sound okay: _I wish I had gone further with my education; I wish I had gone further and considered other options; I wish I had studied further – I only have an associates degree; I wish I had studied further and THEN opened my business; I figured out the puzzle only after I had examined it further;_ etc.